# Tools that list the prototypes in .so library

Tags: linux, command, prototype

Is there a tool(like command) in Linux that list the prototypes in a .so library.

I found `nm` close to my need, but what I got are just symbols.

Comment: What does "prototype" mean for you?

Comment: declaration of function like: `int func(int,char[]);`

Comment: related to [this one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32805/tools-that-list-the-prototypes-in-so-library/32821#32821)

Answer (score 1):

If the library is a C library, it does not contain by itself the signature of the functions. These are in the header files (that the library should give), unless the `.so` library has been compiled with debugging information enabled by `-g` (which is not usual for production libraries).

Even in C++, the `.so` library (without `-g`) don't contain the declaration of involved classes. The mangled names only refer to class or type names...

In short, you need the header files of libraries. Most Linux distributions package them separately from the library itself. For instance, on Debian you have both the `libjansson4` package (containing the `.so`shared library, needed to run applications liked with the Jansson library) and the `libjansson-dev` package (containing the shared objects and header files useful to build an application calling functions in Jansson library). Debian also provides `libjansson-dbg` (for the debugging information or variant of the library) and `libjansson-doc` (for the documentation) packages.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: no you cannot do that (for C).

Longer answer:
You can get "prototypes" as you named them **ONLY** for C++, because functions' declarations are *mangled*. Mangling really means encoding the whole function signature (or prototype if you like) into one string of characters without spaces, e.g:

```
CCertificate::GetInfo(Utils::TCertInfo&) const
```

which is in mangled form:

```
_ZZNK12CCertificate7GetInfoERN5Utils9TCertInfoEE8
```

Mangling was intoduced because of function overloading in C++ (functions with the same name but taking different number of parameters and/or different types). In C you do not have oveloading, so the functions are identified (in shared libraries) by name (which is **NOT** mangled).

To summarise: all functions in shared libraries are identified **by name**, but for C++ these names are mangled names, for C they are not mangled.
Mangling gives you that additional "side effect" that you can see the function signature (e.g. invoking **nm -C**).

Hope that helps.